# SSRS Expression to add two time field columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, sqlreportingservice

I want to add two columns(Time Field-HH:MM:SS) in the SSRS table report.

E.g.:

```
Login_Time     Logout_Time    Total_Time
2:13:10        6:10:05        8:23:15  
3:31:09        6:01:01        9:32:10
```

I have inserted new column in the report to get a total time which should calculate from other two fields from the report. I have tried Format,Timespan, Floor(Sum) but it's throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform Sum() on timespans, but you can do addition and subtraction, what you need to do is subtract the Logout Time from Login Time:

```
=Fields!Logout_Time.Value - Fields!Login_Time.Value
```

This will give you a timespan field with the duration between the log in and log out times.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I need to sum those fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your fields are string data type you can try using:

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!Login_Time.Value).
  AddHours(CDate(Fields!Logout_Time.Value).Hour).
  AddMinutes(CDate(Fields!Logout_Time.Value).Minute).
  AddSeconds(CDate(Fields!Logout_Time.Value).Second),"HH:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect and solved the issue, the SUM is working perfectly.. Thank you so much Alejandro.

Comment: @Arun, you are welcome. If my answer solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.